# Show that any arithmetic progression in $\mathbb{N}$ contains a square free natural number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $(a_n) $ is an arithmetic progression with $a_0= a>$ and with common difference $p$ where $p$ is a prime number and $(a,p)=1$ then show that $(a_n)$ contains a square-free natural number.

I was planning to find some natural number $k$ such that $a+kp$ is squarefree. I was setting $k=p_1p_2p_3 \dots p_k$ where $a=\prod_{i=1}^{k} {p_i}^{q_i}$. But I am confused about the factor $\prod_{i=1}^{k} {p_i}^{q_i-1}+p$

Comment: As an alternative approach, I'd suggest a proof by contradiction. I think it can be shown that if $\left(a_n\right)$ does not contain a square-free natural number and has a prime common difference $p$, then $\textrm{GCD}\left(a, p\right)>1$. Can't be 100% sure if this works though.

Comment: @SunShine Note [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) shows there's an infinite # of primes in $(a_n)$.

Comment: Hint for one way: only one out of four consecutive entries in the sequence is divisible by $2^2$, one of out of nine by $3^2$ etc. Those fractions, ranging over primes other than $p$, add up to less than one.